# What is $X$ in this problem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I captured this picture from the movie *A Beautiful Mind*.

I see this is a problem solving for the dimension of a quotient space, so I guess $W$ is assumed to be a subspace of $V$, and let's also assume $V$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I cannot figure out what $X$ is here. Also, how do I solve this?

[image: p ic]

Comment: Look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/284788/what-is-the-solution-to-nashs-problem-presented-in-beautiful-mind

Comment: I thought this question was closed as a duplicate of copper.hat's post, but apparently it was reopened. Is it substantially different?